# Erasing Polygon Overlay in Spatial Analysis

Tags: algorithm, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

I am using Sutherland Hodgman's Algorithm inorder to clip the polygon overlay for clipping Spatial Query. And I want to implement erase overlay function as well. So suggest me some algorithm like Sutherland Hodgman Algorithm or Can anyone modify this Sutherland Hodgman Algorithm for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct { double x, y; } vec_t, *vec;

inline double dot(vec a, vec b)
{
    return a->x * b->x + a->y * b->y;
}

inline double cross(vec a, vec b)
{
    return a->x * b->y - a->y * b->x;
}

inline vec vsub(vec a, vec b, vec res)
{
    res->x = a->x - b->x;
    res->y = a->y - b->y;
    return res;
}

/* tells if vec c lies on the left side of directed edge a->b
 * 1 if left, -1 if right, 0 if colinear
 */

int left_of(vec a, vec b, vec c)
{
    vec_t tmp1, tmp2;
    double x;
    vsub(b, a, &tmp1);
    vsub(c, b, &tmp2);
    x = cross(&tmp1, &tmp2);
    return x < 0 ? -1 : x > 0;
}

int line_sect(vec x0, vec x1, vec y0, vec y1, vec res)
{
    vec_t dx, dy, d;
    vsub(x1, x0, &dx);
    vsub(y1, y0, &dy);
    vsub(x0, y0, &d);
    /* x0 + a dx = y0 + b dy ->
       x0 X dx = y0 X dx + b dy X dx ->
       b = (x0 - y0) X dx / (dy X dx) */
    double dyx = cross(&dy, &dx);
    if (!dyx) return 0;
    dyx = cross(&d, &dx) / dyx;
    if (dyx <= 0 || dyx >= 1) return 0;

    res->x = y0->x + dyx * dy.x;
    res->y = y0->y + dyx * dy.y;
    return 1;
}

/* === polygon stuff === */
typedef struct { int len, alloc; vec v; } poly_t, *poly;

poly poly_new()
{
    poly p = (poly)malloc(sizeof(poly_t));
    p->len = p->alloc = 0;
    p->v = 0;
    return p;
}

void poly_free(poly p)
{
    if (p->alloc) {
        free(p->v);
        free(p);
    }
}

void poly_append(poly p, vec v)
{
    if (p->len >= p->alloc) {
        p->alloc *= 2;
        if (!p->alloc) p->alloc = 4;
        p->v = (vec)realloc(p->v, sizeof(vec_t) * p->alloc);
    }
    p->v[p->len++] = *v;
}

/* this works only if all of the following are true:
 *   1. poly has no colinear edges;
 *   2. poly has no duplicate vertices;
 *   3. poly has at least three vertices;
 *   4. poly is convex (implying 3).
*/
int poly_winding(poly p)
{
    return left_of(&p->v[0], &p->v[1], &p->v[2]);
}

void poly_edge_clip(poly sub, vec x0, vec x1, int left, poly res)
{
    int i, side0, side1;
    vec_t tmp;
    vec v0 = &sub->v[sub->len - 1], v1;
    res->len = 0;

    side0 = left_of(x0, x1, v0);
    if (side0 != -left) poly_append(res, v0);

    for (i = 0; i < sub->len; i++) {
        v1 = &sub->v[i];
        side1 = left_of(x0, x1, v1);
        if (side0 + side1 == 0 && side0)
            /* last point and current straddle the edge */
            if (line_sect(x0, x1, v0, v1, &tmp))
                poly_append(res, &tmp);
        if (i == sub->len - 1) break;
        if (side1 != -left) poly_append(res, v1);
        v0 = v1;
        side0 = side1;
    }
}

poly poly_clip(poly sub, poly clip)
{
    int i;
    poly p1 = poly_new(), p2 = poly_new(), tmp;

    int dir = poly_winding(clip);
    poly_edge_clip(sub, &clip->v[clip->len - 1], &clip->v[0], dir, p2);
    for (i = 0; i < clip->len - 1; i++) {
        tmp = p2; p2 = p1; p1 = tmp;
        poly_edge_clip(p1, &clip->v[i], &clip->v[i + 1], dir, p2);
    }

    poly_free(p1);
    return p2;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    vec_t c[] = {{200,200}, {400,200}, {400,400}, {200,400}};
    //vec_t c[] = {{100,300}, {300,300}, {300,100}, {100,100}};
    vec_t s[] = {   {50,150}, {200,50}, {350,150},
            {350,300},{250,300},{200,250},
            {150,350},{100,250},{100,200}};
#define clen (sizeof(c)/sizeof(vec_t))
#define slen (sizeof(s)/sizeof(vec_t))
    poly_t clipper = {clen, 0, c};
    poly_t subject = {slen, 0, s};

    poly res = poly_clip(&subject, &clipper);

    for (i = 0; i < res->len; i++)
        printf("%g %g\n", res->v[i].x, res->v[i].y);

    /* long and arduous EPS printout */
    FILE * eps = fopen("test.eps", "w");
    fprintf(eps, "%%!PS-Adobe-3.0\n%%%%BoundingBox: 40 40 360 360\n"
        "/l {lineto} def /m{moveto} def /s{setrgbcolor} def"
        "/c {closepath} def /gs {fill grestore stroke} def\n");
    fprintf(eps, "0 setlinewidth %g %g m ", c[0].x, c[0].y);
    for (i = 1; i < clen; i++)
        fprintf(eps, "%g %g l ", c[i].x, c[i].y);
    fprintf(eps, "c .5 0 0 s gsave 1 .7 .7 s gs\n");

    fprintf(eps, "%g %g m ", s[0].x, s[0].y);
    for (i = 1; i < slen; i++)
        fprintf(eps, "%g %g l ", s[i].x, s[i].y);
    fprintf(eps, "c 0 .2 .5 s gsave .4 .7 1 s gs\n");

    fprintf(eps, "2 setlinewidth [10 8] 0 setdash %g %g m ",
        res->v[0].x, res->v[0].y);
    for (i = 1; i < res->len; i++)
        fprintf(eps, "%g %g l ", res->v[i].x, res->v[i].y);
    fprintf(eps, "c .5 0 .5 s gsave .7 .3 .8 s gs\n");

    fprintf(eps, "%%%%EOF");
    fclose(eps);
    printf("test.eps written\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want to get the difference of the polygons, is that correct? I don't think that's possible with the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm, because you can't exploit the fact that the clipping polygon is convex for this task.

Comment: It is not like difference. I want exactly the opposite of clipping. (i.e) You have both the input and erase overlay, and you get **part of input overlay** as the output such that the common region of the both should not come.

Comment: @MOehm I hope you can understand what I need.